# Date format with javascript do not work in my classic asp page

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function:

```
function montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(dt_exclusao, periodo){

    //var exclusao = dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo);

    //alert(dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo));
    alert(dt_exclusao);
    alert(periodo);

    dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo);

    alert(dt_exclusao);

}
```

Below this line `dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo);` do not work nothing.

If I uncomment this line

```
//alert(dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo));
```

the code after line do not work. Where is my issue?

This way do not work:

```
var dt_exclusao = '26/11/2015';
var periodo = 60;
var nova_data = new Date(dt_exclusao);

    //alert(dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo));
    alert(nova_data);
    alert(periodo);

    nova_data.setDate(nova_data.getDate() + periodo);

    alert(nova_data);
```

But, if I change the format date, it Works, this way.

```
var dt_exclusao = '2015-11-26T00:00:00';
    var periodo = 60;
    var nova_data = new Date(dt_exclusao);

        //alert(dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo));
        alert(nova_data);
        alert(periodo);

        nova_data.setDate(nova_data.getDate() + periodo);

        alert(nova_data);
```

But i receive the date in this format:

```
'dd/mm/yyyy' 

    `enter code here`i tryed: 

        Date.parse(), and 

        stringTodate() and nothing. How can I do to receive the date in one format and change to another?
```

Comment: `alert()` requires a browser. Are you sure it's ASP code?

Comment: I have a asp page and inside some javascript functions. My problem is this function. All alert work, but if i put this: alert(dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo)); do not work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, the date dt_exclusão has a format: **dd/mm/yyyy**, but it not have a time only hour. Will be this the problem?

Comment: What problem? The only thing you've said is that "doesn't work". We don't know what's supposed to do or how it fails to accomplish it.

Comment: See my example on jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pnet/ed3m6t4o/)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this way:

```
function montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(dt_exclusao, periodo){

var arrData = dt_exclusao.split('/');
var exclusaoFormatada = arrData[1] + '-' + arrData[0] + '-' +  arrData[2];
var dias = parseInt(periodo);
var novaData = new Date(arrData[2], arrData[1] - 1, arrData[0]);

novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + dias);}
```

The problem was here:
`dt_exclusao`, but it was receiving a format not recognized. Thanks for all.